# forcing a specific gem version as the default?

Tags: ruby

Let's say I've got three gems installed: package-0.4.0, package-0.5.0, and package-0.5.0-jbfink (I've built the -jbfink one because I made very minor alterations to 0.5.0's source and want to distinguish it from the official releases) .  Is there a gem (or other command) to make one the default?  Right now I've got all three installed, but my shell is picking up executables from package-0.5.0, and I'd rather it default to 0.5.0-jbfink.

Naming 0.5.0-jbfink to 0.5.1 fixes this problem, but I don't want to do that because I'd rather not have conflicts with an officially released 0.5.1 when it comes along.

Answer (score 0):

go to config/environment.rb and specify your gem name a version you would like to use

`config.gem 'will_paginate', :version => '~> 2.3.11'` 
or

```
config.gem 'RedCloth', :version => '3.0.4', :lib => 'redcloth'
```

Hope this is what you are looking for ;)
Petr

Comment: Hi Petr, this isn't a Rails thing so I don't think that will help.  But thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to pick a version from the commandline, it's like

```
$ gem_script_name _0.1.0_ arg1 arg2 ...
```